# How to give access to one of my GCP instances from only my account internal IP address

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

When we are restricting outside world to connect with our vm instances and only our internal vm instances should able to connect the vm instance , this we are not able achieve with firewall rules . Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try to explain more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have load balancer in gcp , the vm instances in the load balancer will be connecting to redis server which is installed in one of the vm instance, I don't want external users to connect to this redis instance except the vm instances present in my account

Comment: Unless you have created a firewall rule with ALLOW, only instances in your VPC can access the Redis instance. Edit your question and include all of the firewall rules.

Comment: Addition to my last comment, provided that your Redis instance does not have a Public IP address.

Comment: Did you use default network in gcp?

Comment: We are using default network in gcp , when we install redis-cli in other instance in the network and pinged to redis server we are able to get response , but when we try to ping redis-server from our application  using jedis client we are not able to connect to redis-server

Comment: @LakshmiKanth where is your application? on the same network or on premise? do you have a rule create to allow traffic to the port used by redis? and as John asked, if you are trying to get from outside the network, does the redis instance has a External IP?